# Can't assign External Testers to new build after expiring the previous one

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Good day,

I have a new version of my app with about 2 builds already like 1.0.0 build 1 and 1.0.0 build 2. I have assigned the External Testers to 1.0.0 build 2 and all is good. I was able to update my TestFlight app with build 2 and do some tests until I saw an issue and uploaded another build(1.0.0 build 3). Then I went into build 2 and clicked "Expire Build". I then went into build 3 and its status is already "Ready to Submit" for External Testers so I tried to add the External Testers group but got this error:

> You can’t submit a build for testing if another build is already in
>   review. Wait until your other build has been reviewed, and resubmit
>   this build.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's wrong but for about 3 hours of waiting and testing to add the External Testers group to my latest build, it finally went through.