# Cannot add TestFlight external testers

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I keep receiving this message after trying to add a build to my external testers group (or adding external testers to the build).

> You can’t submit a build for testing if another build is already in
>   review. Wait until your other build has been reviewed, and resubmit
>   this build.

(note: I have force expired the previous build)

As per [Leolando's question and self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242990/cant-assign-external-testers-to-new-build-after-expiring-the-previous-one), I waited about 24 hours and still no change although my build status is "Ready to submit".

I also tried adding a new build, you never know, and still no change.
I don't want to have to add a new version as it makes no sense...

How should I proceed? Are there specific steps I should follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the build goes to Apple for review **even if you expire it**.
So I just had to wait until I got the first feedback from the Apple review team before I could submit another build.